# MATLAB: Adjustment of x-tick in the box plot

Tags: matlab, boxplot

[image]

Dear all, I have a box-plot of seasonal precipitation as attached below. As you can see in Central region there is a group of five different datasets with five different colors. I need to put x-tick label exactly at the center of these box-plots on x-axis. Right now the x-tick is marked on the last box, i.e., below the black box. Let me know how I can place my ticks exactly at the center of these boxes, so that it represents these sets of five boxes correspond to one region.

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote to produce that plot?  When we answer your question, it'll be easier for us to modify your code so that you can easily port it into your own solution.

Comment: Thanks for that.. I just incorporated it in my code by adjusting mean position of the X-ticks :)

Comment: Cool.  I suggest you answer your own question to let us know what you exactly did.  This way you're telling the community you no longer need help.  Good luck!